# determine which drive in a raid failed windows server

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid10

I'm a volunteer assistant IT guy at a local nonprofit. Over the weekend, we had our main server fail, requiring a reboot. After reboot, we were notified that "a volume initialization is in process."

Here's some data about our system:
Windows Server 2003
RAID 10
4 drives
2 backup drives
Intel Matrix RAID storage console

My initial investigation suggests that the 2 backup drives are not currently in use, which would seem to indicate that whatever drive failed, the system decided to simply rebuild that actual drive.

The question is, how do I determine which drive actually failed? When I look at the Intel Matrix program, every drive seems to be operating normally. Is there a way to sniff out the potentially bad drive, or do we just wait for another failure, hope that one of the hot backup drives is used, and identify the faulty drive that way?

As you can probably tell, I'm very new to this stuff. I appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the S.M.A.R.T values of the drives.

Comment: Wasn't aware of this prior to your comment. Looking at my options - what program would you recommend? I've heard of SpeedFan before and have used it for other problems on some personal PCs.

Comment: I'd just look for "hard drive smart viewer" and some different ones should come up. SpeedFan works too providing it plays nice with your hardware.

Comment: I installed SpeedFan. All drives seem to be normal. I'm at a loss at this point about what happened during the system crashed, what caused it, and what I need to do to protect us from another crash.